# k8s pod cannot communicate with another pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `auth` pod which requires to communicate with `mysql` pod, both are in the same namespace.

```
[root@microservices-python]# kubectl get pods -o wide -n mp3
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
auth-57f6669cc8-4s6c8      1/1     Running   0          5m10s   10.244.0.246   vm1022   <none>           <none>
mongo-64696c8ccf-4n6sv     1/1     Running   0          28h     10.244.0.229   vm1022   <none>           <none>
mysql-6d878c4599-nvnj4     1/1     Running   0          5m28s   10.244.0.245   vm1022   <none>           <none>
rabbitmq-9d6fbf448-7gvr7   1/1     Running   0          27h     10.244.0.237   vm1022   <none>           <none>
```

And here is the service in `mp3` ns.

```
[root@microservices-python]# kubectl get svc -n mp3
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE
auth       ClusterIP   10.111.255.31    <none>        5000/TCP             6m31s
mongo      ClusterIP   10.100.246.252   <none>        27017/TCP            28h
mysql      ClusterIP   10.100.218.240   <none>        3306/TCP             6m49s
rabbitmq   ClusterIP   10.110.92.100    <none>        15672/TCP,5672/TCP   27h
```

Here is I define `mysql` pod.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: mp3
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: mysql-configmap
            - secretRef:
                name: mysql-secret
```

And here is how I define the mysql service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: mp3
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```

When I am trying to connect with mysql with following

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

server = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL(server)

# config
server.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = 'mysql'
server.config["MYSQL_USER"] = 'auth_user'
server.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = 'Auth123'
server.config["MYSQL_DB"] = 'auth'
server.config["MYSQL_PORT"] = 3306

@server.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    input_username = request.form.get("username")
    input_password = request.form.get("password")
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    res = cur.execute(
        "SELECT email, password FROM user WHERE email=%s", (input_username,)
    )
```

Here comes the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/app/server.py", line 64, in login
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 94, in connection
    ctx.mysql_db = self.connect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 81, in connect
    return MySQLdb.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (110)")
```

Anyone knows why and how should I troubleshoot the errors?

Comment: Could you please check if the DNS resolution is functioning correctly within your Kubernetes cluster? Test this by exec-ing into a pod (e.g., the `auth` pod) and running `nslookup mysql.mp3`.

Comment: @HienHoang Here it is. 
`root@auth-57f6669cc8-4s6c8:/app# nslookup mysql.mp3
Server:  10.96.0.10
Address: 10.96.0.10#53

Name: mysql.mp3.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.100.218.240`

Comment: Great DNS working. Next, please check the logs of the mysql pod? This will help us identify if there are any errors or messages indicating why it might be refusing connections. `kubectl logs mysql-6d878c4599-nvnj4 -n mp3`

Comment: @HienHoang here it is `[root@microservices-python]# kubectl logs mysql-6d878c4599-nvnj4 -n mp3
2023-12-26T07:00:56.994473Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-12-26T07:00:56.994506Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

Comment: seem like `auth` pod haven't connect to it. Can you change this config in the python code and try again: `server.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = 'mysql.mp3'`

Comment: @HienHoang That's right! Appreciate! Could you explain why?

Comment: Is it working? Could you try this command `nslookup mysql` in side the pod `auth`?

Comment: @HienHoang the output is the same as `nslookup mysql.mp3`

Comment: If it response like `Name: mysql.mp3.svc.cluster.local` then `server.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = 'mysql'` should also work. So I thought there was some problem with the DNS, but now also start confusing :joy:
Let wait if someone else can explain the problem.

Comment: This use case is very relevant to my interests :D, can you please tell what k8s version and which CNI and DNS solutions you are using in your cluster

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi k8s version is 1.22.4, CNI and DNS solution is `flannel`